# Regex - Include up to a certain character and exclude occurences after

Tags: regex

Want to include the below:

```
com/signup?product=exampleproduct_5

com/signup?product=exampleproduct_10

com/signup?product=exampleproduct_20
```

etc., but exclude the below format:

```
com/signup?product=exampleproduct_5&opc=50cf4090b21efc35b211990818a33db210396d80

com/signup?product=exampleproduct_10&opc=50cf4090b21efc35b211990818a33db210396d80

com/signup?product=exampleproduct_20&opc=50cf4090b21efc35b211990818a33db210396d80
```

etc.

Tried the below but didn't obviously doesn't work hence being here!

```
.*/signup\?product=payroll__(.*)&$
```

Using the "&" following the two numbers is how I think I should differentiate between them both. For example do not include if it has an "&" after the two numbers.

Appreciate all the advice and help as I've spent hours trying and getting nowhere due to my limited knowledge.

Comment: Do you look for this? `.*/signup\?product=payroll__([^&]*)$`

Comment: What is the context?  Are you matching standalone strings, or searching for them in a larger text?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to match only strings that don't have the `&` and other arguments, then:

```
.*/signup\?product=payroll__([^&]*)$
```

If you don't want to exclude cases where there are more arguments, but want to match only the part before the `&` when that is the case, then remove the ending `$` anchor:

```
.*/signup\?product=payroll__([^&]*)
```

Comment: Thanks a million, the top one worked perfectly. Huge help, would have never got that myself. Really appreciate it.